# Determine how a knot ball of vb6 dlls are tied together

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

I'm a bit freaked out because I've been handed this knot ball of vb6 dlls.

It appears the previous developer hard-coded connection strings in to the dlls. The developer quit almost two years ago and I don't have any documentation and I've got several different branches in a VSS database. Servers have move, passwords have been changed.

My first goal is to try and get this contraption up and running. I believe I must first recompile all of the dlls for the new dll changes to take effect. I've found one hiccup where the dll name seems to match the reference in the "Project References" dialog but the project references dialog still says that the reference is MISSING. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

This code is also in an old VSS database that I would like to migrate into our TFS source control server. Is there an easy way to query the VSS server to find the latest changes the developer make so that I can be confident I have the most recent version? The branches do not seem to be named anything logical.

It appears I've discovered someones early attempt at n-tiered development, however the architecture hurts my brain. One layer looks to be about twenty different ways to transform a recordset in to a collection, array or just return the recordset, and a majority of the "business logic" looks to be in the stored procedures.

I think I see why the developer before me and after the first never tried to recompile this project... I can't believe he was lucky enough to get away with it for almost two years, maybe that's why he quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I need to regsvr32 the dlls... oy I just learned what dll hell is.

Answer (score 0):

> I've found one hiccup where the dll
>   name seems to match the reference in
>   the "Project References" dialog but
>   the project references dialog still
>   says that the reference is MISSING.

I think I can at least answer this one. In all likelihood, the dll was not compiled with binary compatibility, or the original dll was not kept to ensure compatibility. Without going into too much detail, you will need to grab the (currently working) dll, set Binary Compatibility in the project, and point to the (currently working) dll for Binary Compatibility. Your recompiled dll should then show up properly.